# Clients / Groups / Users not shown in group policy management console (GPMC)

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, ldap, synology

I have installed the `ActiveDirectory` app on my `Synology DS918+`. Already successfully added users and insert two PCs into the domain.

If I open the `GPMC` on my Windows 10 (v1809) machine, I'm missing the "Clients", "Groups", and "Users" tab *(I started the `GPMC` as domain administrator)*.

How can I make these items available?

**Synology Users and groups**

[image]

**Active Directory Users and Computers**

[image]

**Group Policy Management Console**

[image]

This is what I expected (just a sample image; on this image users, groups and clients are visible):

[image]

Comment: Never created an AD from scratch until now, but seems you are missing organizational units. I'd assume you need to create and define these from Active Directory first, but please anybody correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: To eliminate the GPMC from the equation, what do you see in the `Active Directory Users and Computers` console? That is, are the OUs that are missing from GPMC also missing from ADUC?

Comment: There are the `Users` (dominic) and `Groups` (ecoDMSUser) visible; I have changed the post and added some more screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously showing the GPMC connected to two different domains in your images. The OU's in your second image do not exist in the domain in your first image, which is why you don't see those OU's in the first image.

Comment: I have changed the images and the domain is rendered unrecognizable. It's just a sample image from the internet where you can see the users, groups like I want.

Comment: Clients, Groups, and User are Organizational Units. They do not exist by default and must be created by you. Did you create Organizational Units with those names?

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing the Organizational Unit named **User** with the Container named **Users**. They are not the same thing. Every domain has a Container named **Users** but every domain does not have an Organizational Unit named **User**.